# Controller mapping with multiple query optional parameters not working

Tags: micronaut

I want to map a request to a controller that processes URLs like:

```
/weather?city=London
/weather?city=London&country=GB
```

Notice **city and country are optional parameters**.

This simple controller is:

```
@Controller("/weather")
class WeatherController(...) {

    @Get(produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON])
    fun getWeather(city: String?, country: String?): Flux<Any> = ...
```

But there seems to be some mapping problem:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.codependent.weatherapp.controller.WeatherController.getWeather(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Flux;
    at com.codependent.weatherapp.controller.$WeatherControllerDefinition$$exec1.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:145)
```

**UPDATE:** The project is available on [Github](https://github.com/codependent/micronaut-weather-app).

I've tried several ways to map optional parameters, but none of them worked:

**1) Following URI Path Variables documentation** http://localhost:8080/weather/test1

```
@Get(value = "/test1{?city,country,cityIds}", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON])
fun getWeather(city: Optional<String>, country: Optional<String>, cityIds: Optional<String>) = "The weather is...".toMono()
```

**2) Just indicating the optional, without the actual request parameter mapping** - http://localhost:8080/weather/test2

```
@Get(value = "/test2", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON])
fun getWeather2(city: Optional<String>, country: Optional<String>, cityIds: Optional<String>) = "The weather is...".toMono()
```

**3) The Kotlin way, just expressing the nullability of the params** - http://localhost:8080/weather/test3

```
@Get(value = "/test3", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON])
fun getWeather3(city: String?, country: String?, cityIds: String?) = "The weather is...".toMono()
```

Comment: Can you please file an issue with an example project?

Comment: Done! https://github.com/codependent/micronaut-weather-app

Comment: Created issue: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project is ok, there seemed to be a **problem with IntelliJ that wasn't building it properly**. I changed the building configuration to delegate the process to Gradle and problem solved.

I appreciated @James Kleeh support. Enjoy Micronaut!